# I can't load a html file in public folder from my Firebase function

Tags: html, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I know the path directory is the right path, it's just that I always get the error `'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public/resetp.html'`

My paths are as follows:

```
index.js: firebase/functions/index.js
reset password.html: firebase/public/resetp.html
```

When I go to this endpoint on my function on my website it runs this code:

```
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/./public/resetp.html'));
```

I need to use the sendFile() function so that I can just render the html file and not change the URL since in the html file that I'm trying to load, it gets the parameters of the URL (like the action code) and gets the users input to reset the users password.

Thanks, Nathan

Comment: The content you deploy to Firebase Hosting is not available as local files in Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson What other approach would I have to go through to load up that html page with the correct email parameters, like actionCode or apiKey?

Comment: @DougStevenson I followed the custom email handler and made the script in my html file to change the given users password. It works perfectly if I move the reset.html file into my functions folder, it's just then the css styles and images etc. doesn't load for obvious reasons now. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by making your `public` directory inside your `functions` directory:

```
{
  "hosting": {"public": "functions/public"}
}
```

All of the files in your `functions` directory are deployed with Cloud Functions, and no files outside of it are available.

**Warning:** The files that will be available will be whatever files are *in the public directory at the time you deploy Cloud Functions*. It is up to you to make sure Hosting and functions deploys are kept in sync.

Comment: The public directory is the whole of my website though? How would that work, the functions folder goes to cloud functions and the public folder goes to Firebase Hosting to host it as my website?